# RSpec controller test can't get id params. I don't know how to fix this

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, rspec

Hi I was testing by rspec for rails app now. I have no idea to fix this problem.
here down below. anyone can fix this?

```
1) Items::AddToBasketsController Post #create succuss
     Failure/Error: @item = Item.find(params[:item_id])
     
     ActiveRecord::RecordNotFound:
       Couldn't find Item with 'id'=category=nigiri&discription=test+test&img=%23%3CFile%3A0x00007fc54e9bfc38%3E&name=test1&price=301
     # ./app/controllers/items/add_to_baskets_controller.rb:4:in `create'
     # ./spec/controller/add_to_baskets_controller_spec.rb:43:in `block (4 levels) in <top (required)>'
     # ./spec/controller/add_to_baskets_controller_spec.rb:42:in `block (3 levels) in <top (required)>'
```

add_to_baskets_controller_spec.rb

```
require 'rails_helper'


RSpec.describe Items::AddToBasketsController, type: :controller do 
  let(:user) { create(:user) }
  let(:admin) { create(:admin) }
  let(:first_item)  { create(:first_item, admin_id: admin.id) }
  let(:item_params) { attributes_for(:first_item) }
  
  before do 
    login_user
  end
  
  describe "Post #create" do 
    it "succuss" do
      basket = user.prepare_basket
      expect do
        post :create, params: { item_id: FactoryBot.attributes_for(:first_item) }
      end.to change(basket.basket_items, :count).by(1)
    end
  end
end
```

add_to_baskets_controller.rb

```
class Items::AddToBasketsController < Items::ApplicationController
  def create
    basket = current_user.prepare_basket
    @item = Item.find(params[:item_id])
    basket.basket_items.create!(item_id: @item.id)
    flash[:success] = "your item in basket"
    redirect_to baskets_path
  end
end
```

Comment: FYI usually it's called a cart not a basket in English (I don't know what's your native language, but I used to make the same mistake)

Answer (score 2):

On the line:

```
post :create, params: { item_id: FactoryBot.attributes_for(:first_item) }
```

Your saying that the parameter `item_id` should be `FactoryBot.attributes_for(:first_item)`, which is a hash with all the attributes of `first_item`.

Moreover, to get the ID, you'll need to first create the object. In other word:

```
item_id: FactoryBot.create(:first_item).id
```

Or simply, using your `let`:

```
item_id: first_item.id
```

Comment: thank you so much. it could work. Applicate of you!